# Stray cat and indoor cat

Tags: cats, adoption, strays

Six months ago I moved to North Carolina. In august I noticed a beautiful stray with two colored eyes. At first I’d have to throw chicken into the woods for him because he would not come close. Over time, and after getting a kitten as I needed the emotional support, he warmed up more.

When he comes around, I lock my kitten up as he’s missing his second feline leukemia shot, and let the stray have the option to eat inside or outside. It’s different everyday, I’m assuming due to whatever he deals with that day.

I learned that my husband is being deployed for six months, so I’ve decided to move home.... and as you can guess, the only complicated matter that makes me want to stay is this stray. He occasionally will nap beside me outside, and eat out of my hands. He’s a talker and I’m beyond attached. But...I don’t think he’s ready to be an indoor cat. Let alone, I’m not sure what he has and I’d rather not risk the health of my kitten. I’ve been around my stray enough to know it’s probably not carrying anything serious though. However I did push my bounds and scared him so he scratched me. It seemed infected.

I’d feel horrible to leave him behind. Sometimes he comes back with an injured leg and new scratches. But I also don’t think it’d be fair to make him go on a trip that’s 24 hours of driving and hotel rooms. I got scratched because I picked him up and made him nervous. But he stuck around which I know is great. But I worry how he will be with my kitten who doesn’t know when other cats have had it with playtime. I’m worried how a stray would handle moving to a cold state. And what if he got outside? There is a local place that traps, neuters, and releases strays into their normal environment or a safer one with the rest of the healthy strays.... yet... I’m attached.

This place also says they will take cats for military families and watch them for long periods of time. I’m just worried I can’t get the best of both. Have them help me make him healthy and also keep him here until I’m back. I really should just call and figure it out but I’d like to know what other cat lovers think. I just don’t want to be unfair to my stray cat. I don’t know what’s the best for him, but I love him dearly. And I don’t have too much time left to make a decision. Thank you greatly for all input. (Also yes I know just because I haven’t seen symptoms doesn’t mean he’s not carrying something.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving houses but we feed two stray cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17390/moving-houses-but-we-feed-two-stray-cats) | [How can I move houses with a friendly feral cat I care for?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for)