# How do I move with a colony of ex feral cats who depend on me?

Tags: cats, feral, strays

I currently live in an apartment complex and took on the responsibility 3 years ago to tend to what was then 18 cats and has been up to 24 at once. Mostly all were sick and none were fixed - a couple were pregnant. Within a few months I was able to TNR all and adopt out most of the kittens. Now, I have 16 cats that I need to figure out exactly what to do about- because I am moving!

I want to take them all with me. They will only let me come near them. And now, most of them I can pet. It hasn't been the easiest to get them into carriers for their shots etc but it gets done. For the last 2 years, they come in through a cat door whenever they want to eat, sleep, and hang out. I can't keep them inside full time- I have tried.

The complex I live in has been bought and we all have to go and they hate the cats (the past owners were awesome). What do I do? Where do I move to that they can come too? I'm a renter, I just happened across them one day 3 years ago and they desperately needed help. Now they trust me and depend on me. I am devastated over this. How do I move them all? I'm so scared something horrific will happen if I don't take them as there's already been a few disgusting instances w/ no way to know who did it.
Please help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving houses but we feed two stray cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17390/moving-houses-but-we-feed-two-stray-cats)

Comment: FYI: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for

Comment: I am not sure, if this is a duplicate. Because of the high number of cats. But there are a lots of answered questions here about moving one or two ferral cats, so please search for them as a beginning

Comment: I’m afraid we can’t answer the “Where do I move to that they can come too?” part of your question. That’s unfortunately something that you’ll have to figure out yourself. But have you considered getting a local rescue organization involved? Our local shelter is not just searching homes for cats that are ready for a home, but also for feeding places for ferals - think stables or other, where they will get basic care and food and serve as pest control as a side gig.

Comment: Seconding @Stephie 's suggestion; your best bet is pairing up with some local rescue organizations who can relocate the cats from their current colony to locations where they can serve as "working cats." This is a common solution to cats that are too feral to become housepets, but are in some way endangered in their current situation.

Comment: Something to consider is if the new neigbours would mind. We had most of our community cats moved (which... ended up being dumb, we have an expanding rat population, both in numbers and girth) cause someone in our resident's committee  (something like a HOA combined with a party block office)  didn't like them. I realise the intentions are good, but folks might be unhappy with 16 cats turning up at once. Working with a local shelter/rescue is the best idea here

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate. The number of cats is an order of magnitude higher than the questions we previously answered. But I believe there is not a good way to answer this question, not because the question is unsuitable, but because there is no answer.

Comment: There are not many countries with that many stray cats around. Is it Turkey, Greece, Cyprus? Moving all of them is impossible, but depending on the country, we might suggest some NGOs to help the cats for some time.